# sqlalchemy, postgres, docker

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am struggling to understand why my query below returns the following error, when I past it directly from postgres where it works fine. I have read putting the table name in quotes but this does not work :/.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_name = 'blahh'
db_user = 'blahhd'
db_pass = 'blhd'
db_host = 'localhost'
db_port = 5432

## Connect to to the database
db_string = 'postgres://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(db_user, db_pass, db_host, db_port, db_name)
db = create_engine(db_string)
connection = db.connect()

connection.execute('select cake.name, cake.industry, cake.created_at from cake limit 10;')

connection.close()
```

error:

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "cake" does not exist
LINE 1: ...                                                cake limi...
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Either the table hasn't been created, or you are connecting to the wrong database, or you are connecting with user which isn't allowed to access the table.  If you are spinning up new docker instances, are you sure the table gets created and populated?  Is the process logged?

Answer (score -1):

As explained in the [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#basic-usage), you are missing out the connection object. `create_engine` simply represents a connection resource. You need to connect to it and later close the connection. You may also need to add the method `.fetchall()` to actually view the list of items from your connection.

If you try something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_name = 'blahh'
db_user = 'blahhd'
db_pass = 'blhd'
db_host = 'localhost'
db_port = 5432

## Connect to to the database
db_string = 'postgres://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(db_user, db_pass, db_host, db_port, db_name)
db = create_engine(db_string)
connection = db.connect()

connection.execute('select cake.name, cake.industry, cake.created_at from cake limit 10;').fetchall()

connection.close()
```

Comment: I added what you had advised, but still same error @Dharman